# Получение текста из любого окна

Tags: linux, python-3.x

Задача:
Получать выделенное слово и его контекст (несколько слов слева и справа) из любого окна по нажатию `шотката`.
Пока есть кусочек кода на `Python 3`, но язык не принципиален: главное задачу решить.

Выделенный текст я добываю с помощью `xsel`, а вот как получить контекст?

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к тексту вопроса (нажав [edit]), расшифровку употреблённого вами слова «контекст».

Comment: Есть подозрение, что это невозможно

Comment: Думаю речь идет о написании "бота" который ищет слово и копирует левое и правое поле от него аля ```grep -C 3```, гляньте **xdotool** https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/xdotool.xhtml

Comment: вы хотите screen reader реализовать? В общем случае распознавание текста с картинки придётся делать.